# Issue on Passing One item From PHP Index Array To JSON

Tags: php, html, mysql

can you please take a look at this code and let me know how I can pass "true" to JSON if the query result is positive.

I have following code and as you can see I am trying to export two type of contents as JSON if the condition returns TRUE and HTML if the return is FALSE. I also tried to pass the first item from the `$arr` to `$json[]` by using this assignment `$json[] = $arr[0];`

```
$arr = array("true", "false");
$json = array();
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email ='".$email."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $json[] = $arr[0]; 
  header('Content-Type: text/html');
  echo json_encode($json);   
}else
{
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo '<div id="result">You Do Not Have Login Permission</div>'; 
}
```

can you please tell me this is correct approach or how to achieve the result? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can also pass a boolean for flagging on this. Example:

```
$json = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    $json['response'] = true; 
    $json['message'] = 'Success!';   
} else {
    $json['response'] = false;
    $json['message'] = '<div id="result">You Do Not Have Login Permission</div>';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

Since jQuery is tagged on the question, you can process it on the `success` block if you're using an `$.ajax`:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
success: function(data) {
    if(data.response == false) {
        $('body').html(data.message); // or which part of the dom you want to append
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ghost, but how about returning HTML content in case of getting false in mysqli query?

Comment: I mean sending the HTML to document like echoing  '<div id="result">You Do Not Have Login Permission</div>';

Comment: @Suffii what `dataType` is it that you really want to expect? a JSON or an HTML? i suggest you decide to this and stick to one

Comment: I thought to get HTML in case of false and JSON on True! I am not sure if it is possible or not?!

Comment: @Suffii i suggest you explicitly pick one in this example `JSON`, i revised the answer and check

Comment: great thanks just can you please let me know where dis you get the $json ['response'] and $json ['message']?

Comment: @Suffii this is just a simple array. you can name it any name you want. that way, you can tell if the `if` is true on PHP or not. and the result data (the html message) is separated